# Refreshing Intellisense in Toad for Oracle

Tags: oracle, intellisense, toad

I am using Toad 10.5.1.3

The new objects that I create are automatically not showing up in the intellisense dropdown. The only thing I know works is to shut down Toad and reopen it. There's got to be a better way than that!

How do I refresh the cache for the intellisense dropdown in Toad for Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toad caches results per connection string.

There is a button on your popup that displays objects. Just click it and it will refresh results in cache.

Another way i found out for this is to disable caching of Toad Insight results. Go to options->editor->code assist and disable "cache code insight results".

Of course, this sucks if your dictionary is slow.

Comment: "Toad code insight" is toad's name for intellisense. By "Insight results" they mean list of objects that will be displayed in popup.

It is called "results" because toad does a query on database to get all object that you can access and shows you the results of that query. Cache is used to avoid running that query many times, which can be slow.